# Displaying Angular Material Dialog after x seconds

Tags: angular, angular-material

i'am implementing an angular material Dialog and i want that it be will be displayed after x seconds after clicking the openDialog button 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One simple hacky way would be to wrap your `this.dialog.open()` method call in a `setTimeout()` function like so:

`setTimeout(() => this.dialog.open(...), x000);` where x000 denotes x in milliseconds.